# cryptojs doesn't return true base64 string after encryption

Tags: c#, javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I need to do encryption on plain text using AES CBC techinque but on javascript side. Basically i need to encrypt the URL 
and launch that  URL via ajax call. The system where URL is going to decrypt is wrote in c#. So i have to reply on their
encryption method which is written in c#. I need to use same logic in my javascript so that way it can be decrypt easily in c#

Javascript code

```
var Base64encodedandencryptedtext = "username=abc|password=xyz"
// have a password need to hash on that and then pass into aes encryption function
var hash =  CryptoJS.SHA512("234-234-1231"); //password key
var finalhash = hash.toString((CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
Base64encodedandencryptedtext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(Base64encodedandencryptedtext ,finalhash)

var Base64encodedkey = Base64.encode("encodedkey");
var baseURL = "https://www.xyz.com/"
var DHINquery = baseURL+"?key="+Base64encodedkey+"&value="+Base64encodedandencryptedtext;

//launch via ajax

    $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            async : true,
            url : DHINquery,
            dataType : 'html',
            data : {},          
            success : function (htmlcontent) {
                $("#htmlpage").html(htmlcontent)                
            }, // end success
            complete : function (htmlcontent) {

            }, // end complete
            error : function (htmlcontent) {
            alert("error")
            }
        });
```

C# encryption on their side

```
string Base64encodedandencryptedtext = "username=abc|password=xyz"
Encrypt(Base64encodedandencryptedtext ,passwordkey, "AES") // call that function

 public static string Encrypt(string text, string keyguid, string cryptoService)
    {
        ICryptoTransform transform;
        string text1 = keyguid;
        UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(text);
        string str = CalculateHashToBase64String(text1, enc, "SHA512");
        string s = str.Substring(4, 24);
        string str3 = str.Substring(0, 4) + str.Substring(0x1c, 4);
        string str4 = str.Substring(0, 4) + str.Substring(28, 12);
        string str5 = str.Substring(0, 4) + str.Substring(0x1c, 20);
        byte[] rgbKey = enc.GetBytes(s);
        string str7 = cryptoService;
        byte[] buffer3 = enc.GetBytes(str4);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider provider2 = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        provider2.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        provider2.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        provider2.KeySize = 0x100;
        transform = provider2.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, buffer3);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Transform(bytes, transform)); // return the base64 string
    }
    private static byte[] Transform(byte[] input, ICryptoTransform CryptoTransform)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, CryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                stream2.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
                stream2.FlushFinalBlock();
                stream.Position = 0L;
                buffer = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

While doing debuging on javascript side i am still getting base64string after encryption but c# encryption base64string and javascript
encryption base64string looks different. For that reason webservice doesn't succefully return the data.

I wonder aes plugin i were using is not doing exactly what they are doing in c# side.

Anybody have any idea why? Any help would be a great input.

Comment: This may be related to the fact that _JavaScript_ uses _UTF-16_ internally, irrelevant of the page's character encoding. Also, is _CryptoJS's Base64_ binary safe?

Comment: we are working on javascript side. so we don't have any other choice for encryption.

Comment: Anybody have any idea?

Comment: The problem is either: `1`, the encryption methods are not equivalent, or `2`, the base64 methods give different outputs for equivalent strings. Try to narrow down the problem to, forinstance, encrypted _String_ `x` (or bytes `b`) gets converted to _base64_ `a` in _JavaScript_ and `b` in _c#_. When you've narrowed it down to just a couple lines, it will be clearer which methods don't match up. As I said, these inconsistencies usually come from charsets not matching (which you have no control over in _JavaScript_)

Comment: I said i used plugin on javascript side.It is hardly one line and all other code into plugin library as so many lines of code in the plugin its way diffcult to debug those type of code.

Answer (score 0):

I see quite a few significant difference between how the two compute a key. In the JS, you're hashing a password key, then representing that hash's binary data as base64. Whereas in your C# code, it looks like you're representing the hash's binary data base base64, then taking a substring of that base64 string, then getting the UTF8 bytes of the base64 characters. Those are some really significant differences. The JS side can be simplified a bit, and the C# side can be simplified a lot. On both sides, take the hash of the password key, and use that hash itself as the key. Don't convert the hash to base64. Don't do any other manipulations.

** It would actually be better to use something like PBKDF2, but let's get both sides in sync first.

** Actually since the data is being sent through ajax, if you can use HTTPS, that would be the best option.